# Fallback options for npm failure caused by unpublish

Tags: node.js, npm

We have a `node.js` project, and we want to start managing its dependencies using `npm`'s `package.json` with specified versions for each dependency.

However, we are afraid that one of the packages our project depends on might get `unpublish`ed. Should I worry about unpublishing or is it a rare occurrence? What is the most effective way to handle this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

It is very rare occurence. Never happened to me.

Unpublish is mostly used to remove a published version in which a major bug is reported. Thus, automatic semantic versioning upgrade will not fetch this version until a new one is published.